# Can someone name this part of the roof please?

Tags: roof

I haven't been able to find a diagram of a roof with the exact configuration ours has. I think the board on which our joists rest is called the wall plate but what is the name of the board that sits on the joists and on which the rafters rest?

This is in a garage and I think the plan was to make the roof space bigger for a future conversion because windows are already in place and wiring. The reason I'm asking stems from the fact that I want to sister a couple of joists so I can remove part of one for an opening.

[image]

Comment: Normally both the joist and the rafter rest on the "top plate" or the "wall plate".   The rater is also normally notched  at the top plate.  What you have drawn is atypical.

Comment: That's what I thought too but ours is definitely as in the diagram.The rafter goes nowhere near the wall thoufh it does extend a lot further than I drew so as to form quite a wide soffit.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it's wrong to do it this way, it's atypical because it uses more material for no obvious benefit.  It's effectively a raised top plate.  It's also not clear why the joists are extended.  Perhaps the builder just wanted to be different.

Comment: Hi jwh, this is in a garage and I think the plan was to make the roof space bigger for a future conversion because windows are already in place and wiring. The reason I'm asking stems from the fact that I want to sister a couple of joists so I can remove part of one for an opening. Might I be a bit cheeky and ask if just resting another 2X10 on at least a bit of the "normal" plateon each side of the building but trimmed away so it's not touching the upper plate would be OK. Or does it need to support that as well? I'd be grateful for any advice!

Comment: The home I built in Maryland, that I lived in for 25 years had this type of construction. It was a Cape Cod style home with an 11/12 pitch roof. It was needed for both reasons 2nd floor space and overhang details. I call it a nailer, which those are typically further defined by their purpose, in this case, a nailer for the rafters. Raised plate fits too. Purlin, IMHO is a bit of a stretch since that term is seems to always applied to a member that is applied to the face of studs or rafters or a mid span support under rafters.

Comment: Thanks, nice to hear from someone who actually has built this type of roof, Nailer for the rafters or rafter nailer is what I'll call it.

Comment: Don't know why they did that; only idea I could come up with is if they wanted the soffit higher, for a wider window view? maybe noon sunlight? (but you indicate this is the garage) Does it help the roof-line match the house? or avoid a roof valley?

Comment: @troubleshooter I think the reason was to maximis the attic space, there are skylights already fitted for an intended conversion. There are no valleys it's a freestanding building.

Comment: "Nailer"? Might as well call it "board". :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an official standard name for this specific scenario, but I'd call it a *[purlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purlin)* or an *elevated wall plate*, maybe. A diagram in [this discussion](https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/question/stick-framed-equivalent-to-high-heel-energy-truss) has it as a *raised top plate*. [This article](http://www.jwkhomeinspections.com/blog/collar-ties-rafter-ties-purlins-san-antonio-home-inspector.html) discusses purlins as an intermediate rafter support member.

jwh20 is right in that this is a non-standard roof framing method, but there are a few reasons it may have been done (one of which you mentioned--attic space). Another is to create an "energy heel" or "raised heel", where there's more vertical space for insulation. Yet another would be to raise the fascia/soffit height to clear windows or improve appearance (in the case of a very steep pitch). In your case the ceiling joists may have been run through to create backing for the soffit, which is often added later at a lower level.